# android.hardware.camera2 face recognizing

Tags: android, camera, detection, face-recognition

I have problem with:

```
Face[] faces = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACES);
```

because it always returns the length 0;

this is my initializes:

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE,CameraMetadata.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_SIMPLE); 

mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(); mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,mCaptureCallback,mBackgroundHandler);
```

this is my callback part:

```
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

@Override
public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                               @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                               @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
    Face[] faces = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACES);
    // face.length is always 0
}
```

I see camera preview correctly

Any idea what's missed?